# Tkinter issue with multiple callback functions and use of after()

Tags: python, tkinter, callback, tk-toolkit

I am working on a very long piece of code and one which I would like to take GUI input more than once in multiple windows.

The code is too long and wouldn't make much sense if I put it in here, but here's the layout of my code:

```
callback1():
    do something
```

```
tkinter stuff, using callback1()    
...
lots of other code (none to do with tkinter)
...

callback2():    
    do something else

tkinter stuff using callback2()

some more code (none to do with tkinter)

mainloop()
```

Sorry for the vague structure, but this is more or less the layout of my code. The problem is though, that mainloop() never seems to be reached, and my other code in between the callbacks relies on the input from the GUI and so it crashes.

I've tried:

```
callback1():
    do something
    after(500, callback1)
```

```
tkinter stuff, using callback1()    
...
lots of other code (none to do with tkinter)
...

callback2():    
    do something else
    after(500, callback1)

tkinter stuff using callback2()

some more code (none to do with tkinter)

after(0, callback1)
after(0, callback2)
mainloop()
```

But had no luck. Can anyone help me with the correct usage of after() (or any other function) so that I can just get the GUI to display?

Answer (score 3):

GUI frameworks like tkinter are *event-driven*. They start running when they start their `mainloop()`. Everything before that is basically set-up and housekeeping.

After the mainloop starts, the *only pieces of your code* that they run are callbacks that you've attached to interface elements like buttons or to timers with `after`.

These callbacks must be relatively short and should not take a long time. The GUI toolkit calls the function you provided to handle an event in the mainloop. So while your callback is running, no further events are being processed and the GUI is effectively frozen. If that only takes a little while (say 50 milliseconds) nobody will notice.
But if you want to run a computation that takes several seconds to complete, you cannot do that in a callback without freezing the GUI.

You could consider doing the long-running job in a second thread. But in CPython only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode for technical reasons. However (especially in Python 3) threads are forced to relinquish the CPU regularly, so this might be a workable solution.

Another solution is to farm long-running jobs out to a separate process using `multiprocessing`. In this case you do have to set-up communication between the processes via e.g. a `Queue`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't organize your code like that.  Presumably, you have something similar to this:

```
import tkinter as tk

mainwindow = tk.Tk()
mainwindow.geometry("300x200")
mainwindow.title("MyWindow")

label = tk.Label(mainwindow, text="Enter stuff, then click the button.")
label.pack()

var = tk.StringVar()
entry = tk.Entry(mainwindow, textvariable=var)
entry.pack()

#callback1():
def onclick():
    #do something with var.get() ?
    pass

button = tk.Button(mainwindow, text="click me", command=onclick)
button.pack()

#lots of other code (none to do with tkinter):
print("The value I need is: {}".format(var.get()))

mainwindow.mainloop()
```

The output of that program is:

> The value I need is:

You need to put your code in either the callback function, or another function that is called by the callback function:

```
def my_func():
    print("The value I need: {}".format(var.get()))

def onclick():
    #do something with var.get()
    my_func()

button = tk.Button(mainwindow, text="click me", command=onclick)
```

Now, the output is something like:

> The value I need is: 10

`tkinter` is a GUI framework, and it responds to events that happen in your window.  The way you respond to an event is to wrap your code in a callback function and pass the function to tkinter, which will then call the function at the proper time.  You do not write arbitrary code in the middle of a tkinter program.

The `after()` method does not seem appropriate, because it essentially says:

> After the mainloop starts, execute this function.

You can delay the execution for however many seconds you want--but that doesn't mean that the user will have entered the data you need by then.  What you want to do is execute your code after the user enters their data, and usually you do that by responding to a button click, where the button says, `Submit`, or some other event.

Comment: Indeed, I realized my error. After some shuffling of my callback functions (dumping the entire program essentially into one of the callback functions), it worked like a charm and I included a initiate button. Thank you for the reply!